# Target Audience in CEWP Snippet not working

Tags: 2013, audience-targeting, cewp

I am trying to add a **CEWP snippet with Target Audience** applied to a Page Layout. However the Target Audience is not working when I add a CEWP as a snippet.

However, if I apply a CEWP to a Web Part Zone via the browser, Target Audience works.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there a fix?

**UPDATED OCTOBER 31:**

```
<!--CS: Start Content Editor Snippet--><!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>--><!--MS:<WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart xmlns:WebPartPages="namespace" runat="server" webpart="true">--><!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><div class="ms-webpart-chrome ms-webpart-chrome-fullWidth "><div WebPartID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" HasPers="true" id="WebPart" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody " OnlyForMePart="true" allowDelete="false" style=""><div class="ms-rtestate-field"></div><div class="ms-clear"></div></div></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW--><!--MS:<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">--><!--MS:<Title>--><!--SPM:Add to Library--><!--ME:</Title>--><!--MS:<FrameType>--><!--SPM:None--><!--ME:</FrameType>--><!--MS:<Description>--><!--SPM:$Resources:core,ContentEditorWebPartDescription;--><!--ME:</Description>--><!--MS:<IsIncluded>--><!--SPM:true--><!--ME:</IsIncluded>--><!--MS:<ZoneID>--><!--SPM:ImportedPartZone--><!--ME:</ZoneID>--><!--MS:<PartOrder>--><!--SPM:0--><!--ME:</PartOrder>--><!--MS:<FrameState>--><!--SPM:Normal--><!--ME:</FrameState>--><!--MS:<Height>--><!--ME:</Height>--><!--MS:<Width>--><!--ME:</Width>--><!--MS:<AllowRemove>--><!--SPM:true--><!--ME:</AllowRemove>--><!--MS:<AllowZoneChange>--><!--SPM:true--><!--ME:</AllowZoneChange>--><!--MS:<AllowMinimize>--><!--SPM:true--><!--ME:</AllowMinimize>--><!--MS:<AllowConnect>--><!--SPM:true--><!--ME:</AllowConnect>--><!--MS:<AllowEdit>--><!--SPM:true--><!--ME:</AllowEdit>--><!--MS:<AllowHide>--><!--SPM:true--><!--ME:</AllowHide>--><!--MS:<IsVisible>--><!--SPM:true--><!--ME:</IsVisible>--><!--MS:<DetailLink>--><!--ME:</DetailLink>--><!--MS:<HelpLink>--><!--ME:</HelpLink>--><!--MS:<HelpMode>--><!--SPM:Modeless--><!--ME:</HelpMode>--><!--MS:<Dir>--><!--SPM:Default--><!--ME:</Dir>--><!--MS:<PartImageSmall>--><!--ME:</PartImageSmall>--><!--MS:<MissingAssembly>--><!--SPM:Cannot import this Web Part.--><!--ME:</MissingAssembly>--><!--MS:<PartImageLarge>--><!--SPM:/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif--><!--ME:</PartImageLarge>-->

<!--MS:<AuthorizationFilter>--><!--SPM:;;;;Surrey Owners--><!--ME:</AuthorizationFilter>-->
<!--MS:<IsIncludedFilter>--><!--SPM:;;;;Surrey Owners--><!--ME:</IsIncludedFilter>-->

<!--MS:<ExportControlledProperties>--><!--SPM:true--><!--ME:</ExportControlledProperties>--><!--MS:<ConnectionID>--><!--SPM:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000--><!--ME:</ConnectionID>--><!--MS:<ID>--><!--SPM:g_f6a99049_ea1e_4d0a_a658_7cd3a692b503--><!--ME:</ID>--><!--MS:<ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor">--><!--SPM:/SiteAssets/userlinkToLibrary.html--><!--ME:</ContentLink>--><!--MS:<Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor">--><!--ME:</Content>--><!--MS:<PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor">--><!--ME:</PartStorage>--><!--MS:<ID>--><!--SPM:g_b7bd5f1c_9e2d_432b_ab01_18fe66febbc5--><!--ME:</ID>--><!--ME:</WebPart>--><!--ME:</WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>--><!--CE: End Content Editor Snippet-->
```

Comment: **UPDATE**: I still CANNOT get the Target Audience to work in a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) snippet that is applied to a page layout. If anyone can figure this out, please let me know.